# django coverage not covering the urls despite writing specific tests for the urls

Tags: python, django, coverage.py

in my app named backoffice_engine, my urls.py file is as follows

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('test/', views.test, name='test'),
    path('', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
    path('dashboard/', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
    path('add_new_client/', views.add_new_client, name='add_new_client'),
    path('edit_client/<int:client_id>', views.edit_client, name='edit_client'),
    .....some more paths....
    ]
```

my test_urls.py file for this urls.py file is as follows

```
from django.test import SimpleTestCase
from django.urls import reverse, resolve
from backoffice_engine.views import *

class TestBackofficeEngineUrls(SimpleTestCase):

    def test_test_url(self):
        url = reverse('test')
        self.assertEquals(resolve(url).func, test)

    def test_blank_url_uses_dashboard_function(self):
        url = reverse('dashboard')
        self.assertEquals(resolve(url).func, dashboard)

    def test_add_new_client(self):
        url = reverse('add_new_client')
        self.assertEquals(resolve(url).func, add_new_client)

    def test_client_detail(self):
        url = reverse('client_detail', args=['1'])
        self.assertEquals(resolve(url).func, client_detail)
```

my understanding is runnning coverage on this file should result in coverage report showing that the following urls have been covered by unit tests.

however coverage report for backoffice_engine.urls.py is zero missing by default.
the report only is checking only the first 3 lines of the urls.py file

[image: coverage report image]

Comment: It does say the coverage is 100%. Maybe it just treated urlpatterns and the rest of it as one line?

Answer (score 0):

Coverage can't tell you which url patterns were used. Line 4 is the start of one long multi-line statement which assigns all of the URL patterns.  It is run just once, when urls.py is imported.

For example, line 7 isn't executed when you visit the "dashboard/" URL.  It's executed when the program starts up, to add a pattern for "dashboard/" to the list of all patterns.